# Visio Org Chart with Connector Text

Tags: visio, connector

I've tried all day (unsuccessfully) to create an org chart that displays a variable as the connector text.

I am not a developer and new to visio.

Basically, my data looks like this:

| ID | Name | Reports_to | Connector_txt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person A |  |  |
| 2 | Person B | 1 | direct |
| 3 | Person C | 1 | direct |
| 4 | Person D | 2 | legal |
| 5 | Person E | 2 | direct |
| 6 | Person F | 3 | financial |

Please note that it is important to display the text above the connector and not within the shape.
Further, the data has to be connected to an Excel file so that it can be maintained in Excel and Visio is just used for visualization. Hence, the solution should work without manually adjusting everything, all the time.

I also tried flow charts etc. but they look totally messy (not simply top to bottom). But I am generally open to using another template than "org chart" if it results in a clean vertical visual (no swimlanes etc.).

Thank you so much for any thoughts on this :)

Bonus: If it would be possible to group persons with team frame or container from the excel data (e.g., by adding a column "department") that would be awesome!

EDIT: Here is some manually created visual on how I wanted it to look like
[Org Chart with Connector Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhcsy.png)

Comment: What MS Visio version do you use ? If Visio Plan 2, you can use its build-in add-in named [Data Visualiser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7HwLzQFqEY)

Comment: Hey,
thanks for the suggestion but the Data Visualizer has very limited options. It looks like Visio does not want to add connector text to an org chart because (I guess) it becomes very messy if there are too many entries. I try to restructure the data to work with the built-in solutions. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Visio's built in Charting solutions enough to say it is not possible out of the box, but I would let Visio generate the chart as it does and only after this would run a macro over the drawing that collects the Reports_to and Connector_text properties, identifies the right connector and finally sets it text to the desired value.
You said, you're not a developer, I'm sure we can help in this matter.

Same for your second wish.

Comment: Hey,
thanks for the answer. I try to restructure the data to work with the built-in solutions. If the data set becomes too large it looks quite messy with the connector texts I guess, so you would have to ensure that the connector texts have a certain distance to each other which sounds like a challenging problem. I close the thread. Thanks anyways.